# Send a javascript variable to django view

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I am fetching the current url of the browser (which keeps changing) in a javascript variable (say var_url). I have a django model Url. I want to create its object using a view function `create_url()`.

Earlier When I used a form, I used `request.POST['field']`. Now I don't have a form and I want to pass the value of var_url. How can that be done?

This was my view function when I was using a form:

```
def create_url(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    text=request.POST['field']
    url_result=Url.objects.get_or_create(
        url_text=text
        )
    return HttpResponse('Url Object Created')
```

And the following was my form:

```
<form name='urlForm' method="post" action="{% url 'create_url'%}" id="create" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id="myurl" name="field"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Now rather than a form, I have this:

```
<div id='results'></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('message',function(e){
        results.innerHTML = e.data;
    });
</script>
```

I want to send the content of div tag to my view function.

Comment: Please add the code posing the problem

Comment: add your form and template

Comment: @DirkHorsten  I have added the code. Please check the updated question.

Comment: @seuling Please check the updated question.

Comment: What data you want to send?

Comment: @seuling The content of div tag gets updated by the script below it. I want to send that content to my view.

Comment: oh I understand it. you want to send `<div id='results'>this data</div>` this data, right?

Comment: @seuling Exactly!

Comment: ok I will write answer soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two way - using `form` and using `ajax` for sending data.

Assume that you have data called `result_data` in js.

#### First, use existing `form`

In this way, you have to update your inner data to form field (i.e. make hidden `result_data` field to send form data).

```
<form name='urlForm' method="post" action="{% url 'create_url'%}" id="create" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="myurl" name="field"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="result_data" value="" id="js_data_input">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then you add javascript code to add your `result_data` to your hidden input value. Maybe like this..
(I'm not good at javascript, so make it your own way)

```
<script>
    $('#js_data_input').val(result_data)
</script>
```

Then just submit your form with this data.

#### Second, use `ajax`

If you send your data without submit form (it means that not reload/escape current page), you can use `ajax`.

When using ajax, you have to make other view that receive your ajax request.

If you don't know about ajax, please check [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) or other web site.

This is example for send `result_data` using ajax

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/your/path/to/ajax_view/url/',
    data: {
      'result_data': result_data,
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.result == 'ok') {
        alert(response.message);
      } else {
        alert('Failed');
      }
    }
  })
```

> You have to add `csrfmiddlewaretoken`. Else, you got 403 forbidden error. You can make csrfmiddlewaretoken by js or just using `{{ csrf_token }}` from django.